# Azure Functions v1 timer triggered function cannot start due to Windows Platform FIPS issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to develop a function app that uses a timer trigger and I'm getting an issue with the Windows Platform FIPS that prevents the timer-triggered function to start locally.  Here's the code that's causing the error (it's the default timer-triggered function):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
}
```

When I try to run this function in func.exe, it produces the following error:

```
The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. mscorlib: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
```

This exact code works on another dev environment that I have access to.  What do I need to do to fix these Windows Platform FIPS issues so that the timer trigger will run?

Thanks!

Comment: Any update? If you have managed to solve it, feel free to post your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment does need this FipsAlgorithmPolicy somewhere, disable it for Azure function only.

1. In File Explorer, open `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.4.0\cli\func.exe.Config`, add `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>` under `<runtime>` element. Note that in this way, you have to repeat this step once new function cli is released.
2. Similarly, if you use Storage Emulator locally, open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config`, add `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>` under  element.

Else just disable FipsAlgorithmPolicy for your computer.

1. In search box or right click on Start button and click Run, input `regedit` to open Registry Editor.
2. In address bar(View>Address Bar), navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy`.
3. Double click on `Enabled`, change Value data to 0.

Comment: So, disabling it in the func.exe.config does, in fact, get rid of the error within func.exe, but the timer function still doesn't instantiate and run.  I'm still researching the issue.

Comment: @RyanT4S If you use Storage emulator locally, also need to disable the policy in emulator config file, see my update.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I'm not having that issue anymore since we abandoned that VM and created a new one from scratch with Win10.  The infrastructure team had installed multiple versions and editions of Visual studio and then uninstalled them on that machine leaving only VS2017pro.  I feel like that just hosed the packages on the machine.  The old VM is still out there, though, so I'll see if your suggestion resolves the issue there.