# the lister for function was unable to start. time trigger function

Tags: docker, azure-functions

I have time trigger function which is working locally. I build the solution into a docker container. When I start the image locally it works again but when I start start the image on windows server 2019 I get this error:

```
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'PlayerSummary' was unable to start.
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: Name or service not known
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToke
n)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancell
ationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boo
lean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationC
ontext, CancellationToken token)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationC
ontext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.StorageBaseDistributedLockManager.TryAcquireLeaseAsync(CloudBlockBlob blob, TimeSpan leasePeriod, Str
ing proposedLeaseId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storag
e\Singleton\BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs:line 133
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.StorageBaseDistributedLockManager.TryLockAsync(String account, String lockId, String lockOwnerId, Str
ing proposedLeaseId, TimeSpan lockPeriod, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azur
e.WebJobs.Host.Storage\Singleton\BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs:line 84
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.SingletonManager.TryLockAsync(String lockId, String functionInstanceId, SingletonAttribute attribute,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean retry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\S
ingletonManager.cs:line 113
```

my function call looks like this:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(PlayerSummary))]
    public async Task PlayerSummary([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        var endpoint = "https://example.com";
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var date = start.ToString(Format);
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Request
        {
            DateStart = date,
            DateEnd = date,
            WhiteLabels = [1, 2]
        });
        var request = new StringContent(
            body,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");
        var responseBody = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var response = await _client.PostAsync(endpoint, request);
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var resultSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerSummary[]>(responseBody);
                await _context.PlayerSummaries.AddOrUpdatePlayerAsync(resultSet);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                await _monitor.LogInfo(nameof(PlayerSummary), responseBody, start, DateTime.UtcNow);
            }
            else
            {
                await _monitor.LogWarning(nameof(PlayerSummary), body, responseBody, start, DateTime.UtcNow);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await _monitor.LogError(nameof(PlayerSummary), body, responseBody, start, e, e.Message);
            logger.LogError($"{nameof(PlayerSummary)} ERROR at {DateTime.UtcNow}: {e.Message}");
        }
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PlayerSummary)} executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/ProgressPlay
RUN cd /src/ProgressPlay && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureWebJobsStorage="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://host.docker.internal" \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

I have checked and my storage emulator is running
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- If your firewall restricts func from accessing the Storage Account, then this error may be reported. The firewall is one of the reasons that the listener cannot access the virtual Storage Emulator.

  When running the function locally, all triggers except httptrigger need to use the Storage Emulator. If the firewall restricts the listener's access to virtual storage, problems can occur when performing functions. That's why you don't get errors with httptrigger, because it doesn't use a virtual Storage Emulator.

  Try disabling the firewall and see if that resolves the issue.
- Check if the function and Storage Emulator are on same drive.

Install Azurite Emulator and see if listener responds. Below is the Docker command

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
```

This will help you in running Azurite Image

```
docker run -p 10000:10000 -p 10001:10001 -p 10002:10002 \
    mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
```

For further quarries check [Azurite Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json&tabs=docker-hub#install-and-run-azurite).

Also check the SO where same discussions were going on [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52712334) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59026924) and [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/357)